# Android how to create a custom adjustments to an app from apk file?

Tags: android, customization, whatsapp, whatsapi

First I will just say this is only for my personal use and will be used only on my phone.

I saw allot of whatapp custom client (mods) on the internet for an example whatsapp plus.

I am developing on android for some time now but I wasn't enable to fiend the way they does it, the only way that I did manged to accomplish is editing the xml files of the original apk. But the adjustment that i am thinking about requires the code files that I can't get (ofcourse). I have tried to Decompile the apk but I get allot of SMALI files and to make use of them seems nearly impossible.

I wouldn't even bother but the amount of custom apks out there and not just for whatsapp is huge and making it looks relatively easy, Can someone explain how they all do that ?

Sorry if stack-overflow is not the right place to ask this question but my main topic is code devolving so I think it is related..

Comment: you basically need to know how to `decompile apk to java classes android`. Try searching. SHould take not more than minute to find an answer

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I did came across this option, but then I tried to do that I got a messed up files that won't ever go to an apk version once again. Are you sure this is the only way ? to decompile into class files and the manually fix the entire project ? It can take months..

Comment: probably not the only way, but it is a way. I don;t think that it is going to take months.

Comment: Considering the amount of files that It is creating for an apps like whatsapp it may take months and to think that all I need is just to make whatsapp name the photos that he is saving relating to the sender name. It basically 1 line of code =\ Anyways I will check this option hopefully there is another more short way.

Comment: just be warned that you likely already violate some laws by only decompiling whatsapp apk.